# Magento : Check if customer Page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

How to check current page is Customer Account page or not?

I have used this but it's only for My Account Page

```
<?php $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
echo $action->getFullActionName('_');
if($action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_account_index")
{

}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code, for customer dashboard links below handler is alwasy there, so you can check below handler

```
if(in_array('customer_account',$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles())){
  // your code 
}
```

Comment: @KetanKpBorada You are always welcome

Comment: will it works when i install new extension regarding customer. i.e-Testimonial Tab, Zendesk Tab, My Quotation Tab??

Comment: its depand on the extension but this works with default

Answer (score 3):

you can add check with **getModuleName**

```
<?php $modulename = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();

if($modulename=="customer" && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{

}?>
```

Comment: Good logic but it also not works for `review/customer/`,`sales/order/history/`,`/wishlist` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please use bellow code to identify my account page :

```
$handle= $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
if(in_array('customer_account',$handle) && in_array('customer_logged_in',$handle)){
 //your code here for my account page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all condition for all action of account pages like below:

```
<?php $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
if($action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_account_index" || $action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_account_edit" || $action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_address_new")
{

}?>
```